# Blazor await LocalStorage.GetAsync dont wait

Tags: async-await, local-storage, blazor

I would like to read information from the LocalStorage within a .razor file and then execute further source code on the basis of this. The problem is that he doesn't wait when reading from the LocalStorage.‎

```
@{
    var loggedIn = IsLoggedIn();

    if (loggedIn.Result)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

```
private async Task<bool> IsLoggedIn()
{
    var result = await LocalStorage.GetAsync<Account>("AccountInfo");
    _account = result.Value;

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_account?.Name);
}
```

As soon as it reaches the "await LocalStorage.GetAsync" and I continue using debugger, "if (loggedIn.Result)" is called without waiting for the result of the await.‎

‎What could be the reason?‎

‎Best regards and thank you for ideas.‎

Comment: Please post in English.

Comment: Related SO question: [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not `await`ing the call to `IsLoggedIn`, so as soon as the code hits the `await LocalStorage.GetAsync` call, execution continues on the main thread.

You cannot use `await` in razor markup/inline code, so you need to do things differently.

try something like this instead:

```
@if (loggedIn)
{
 // do something
}

@code 
{
  bool loggedIn = false;

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    loggedIn = await IsLoggedIn();
    StateHasChanged();
  }

  private async Task<bool> IsLoggedIn()
  {
    var result = await LocalStorage.GetAsync<Account>("AccountInfo");
    _account = result.Value;

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_account?.Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `.Result` in the original code does an implied (a)wait.

Comment: That was not the question - it was basically "why does the code reach that line before expected" and the implied question - "how do I do this?", and that is why I gave this answer. And as `.Result` blocks the calling thread, it is not a good idea to use it in a razor inline code block. I would have expected a warning at the very least - but I have never written this code, so don't know if it does warn?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear if there is a problem or even a warning. Getting code out of the markup is the right direction.